# Changing lines while printing array

Tags: java, println

I'm trying to read a txt file and print the line opposite. for example: 
txt:

```
3 //size of matrix  
3 4 5  
5 6 7  
6 7 8
```

output should be:

```
6 7 8  
5 6 7  
3 4 5
```

I wrote a program. the program prints:

```
5 6 7  
3 4 5
```

which is without the first line: `6 7 8`.

What is my mistake?

```
public static void main (String[] args)  {
   int matrixSize = StdIn.readInt(); 
   String [] array = new String [matrixSize]; 
   for (int i=0; i <= matrixSize-1; i++)
   { 
      array[i] = StdIn.readLine();
      StdOut.println(array[i]);
   } 
   for (int j=matrixSize-1; j >= 1; j--)
   {
      StdOut.println(array[j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: If your matrix has 3 rows, the first integer in your input should be 3, not 2

Comment: Why is that? matrix is 3*3 so the size of the matrix should be 3.

Comment: That's exactly my point. Your input starts with 2, so only 2 rows are read.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop will iterate from the last element to the second one.

```
for (int j=matrixSize-1; j >= 1; j--)
```

Change to also include the first element

```
for (int j=matrixSize-1; j >= 0; j--)
```

Also it seems that `StdIn.readInt()` doesn't consume the new line character. So when you do a `StdIn.readLine()` after that you get an empty line. That empty line is what remains from the first line after you have scanned the number. A simple workaround for that would be to obtain `matrixSize` like this :

```
String text = StdIn.readLine();
int matrixSize = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

Comment: Works amazing. Thank you so much! I understood my problem :)